# Can a present-participle (compound) verb which could function as an adjective be further modified with -ly become an adverb?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, phrasal-verbs, parts-of-speech, present-participles

For example, if the height of an platform is such as to be sickness-inducing, then could the platform be said to be sickness-inducingly high?

Or take the example of mind-boggling -> mind-bogglingly. For some reason this just feels much more natural, and I can't figure out if there's any other reason for that than the fact that it's simply more commonly encountered. Is there any intrinsic difference between the two, and are they both completely valid?

Comment: Why shouldn’t it be considered one? The act of inducing sickness differs from the act of boggling a mind seemingly only in that sickness is (unlikely mind this this context) an uncountable noun like fish or wheat. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The direct object is not considered part of the verb, normally. _Go figure_ might be considered a compound verb, in that it consists of two verbs. But "compound verb" doesn't have a precise definition, which means that it's useless arbitrary terminology, rather than the name of a property that can be discovered.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're asking about very informal speech, in which you can do just about anything.

Comment: *boggling* is accepted as a present participle adjective; *inducing* isn’t. *It was very boggling.* *\*It was very inducing.*

Comment: Ok the question is why that is. Boggling is self-contained. Inducing requires to be specified what it was that was being induced.

Comment: 'The platform is sickness-inducingly high' is clear, grammatical taking 'sickness-inducingly' as a [novel] compound adverb (it is morphologically soundly constructed) ... but the coinage strongly suggests quite strongly a flippancy that may be inappropriate. It would be surprising to see it used in an official document.

Comment: What do you mean by flippancy?

Comment: Oxford Languages gives a good definition spread.

Answer (score -1):

"Sickness inducing" is an adjective, in the same way that "breathtaking", "factfinding" and life-giving" are adjectives.

Constructions such as "breathtakingly high" are unproblematic because the adverb "breathtakingly" has been established in the language. The same goes for "heart-breaking" and "self-defeatingly".

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/breathtakingly?q=breathtakingly)) **breathtakingly** adverb  /ˈbreθteɪkɪŋli/
> ​in a way that is very exciting, impressive or surprising
> • a breathtakingly expensive diamond

However, "sickness-inducingly" is not a word in English.

[image]

Neither do you find the adverbs "fact-findingly", "life-givingly" although the corresponding adjectives are well known.

Mind-bogglingly does exist, so it sounds natural. You find plenty of construction where this adverb modifies an adjective. ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mindbogglingly%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en))

- mindbogglingly (stupid, startling, useful, large, sublime, etc.)

> I can't figure out if there's any other reason for that than the fact that it's simply more commonly encountered. Is there any intrinsic difference between the two […]?

The fact that one (mind-bogglingly) is found often is certainly a reason for theimpression that it is natural—since thereby we have well identified something real— whereas the other (sickness- inducingly) does not cause this impression since  there is still an effort of identification to a given reality to be made first, and that this effort is fruitless.

But this is not all. The very reason for not finding "sickness-inducingly", that is the fact that in life as we know it, height, for instance, not being  a sickness-inducing agent, speakers could never be incited to use the combination "sickness-inducing heights" ([sickness-inducing height,sickness-inducing heights](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sickness-inducing+height%2Csickness-inducing+heights&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)), more essentially, the fact that it is not conceivable, results in a void in our minds and more generally in the minds of the knowledgeable individuals. In an exaggerated way it is a construction like "stone-lifting eyes" and stone-liftingly eyed" to which we can't relate at all.

The apprehension of the corresponding adverb is then that much more difficult as it is found at an even more remote stage of difficulty as far as the thought process that makes us grasp words. If there are things that are sickness inducing, we do not commonly experience such a process in which sickness or growing sickness is associated with a given action or situation. There is semantically, as far as meaning reflects reality something intrinsic to the term that prevents its use, its naturalness.

Comment: While functioning as adjectives, are they not adjectives in the forms of present-participle verbs?

Comment: Heights definitely induce sickness (ask me), and those would be sickness inducing heights. https://www.english-corpora.org/iweb/?c=iweb&q=113395552

Comment: @TinfoilHat Merely great altitude does that ([High Life: A History of High-Altitude Physiology and Medicine]); it happens too rarely, because practically no one goes to these places, and nobody got sick at the Olympic games in Mexico (2240 m elevation); therefore that has no impact.

Comment: @Seekinganswers What can be said is that the form, as it comes from a verb, confers to the adjective a particular quality that regular adjectives don't have; for this reason it fits into a category of adjectives called *verbal adjectives*. This quality is thatof attributing to the noun they modify a characteristic that involves *a process*, unlike regular adjectives. (ex. : a much *argued* case, a *trying* set of circumstances ([ref.](https://glossary.sil.org/term/verbal-adjective)). (1/2)

Comment: @Seekinganswers  Grammatically, they are fully adjectives and not at all verbs; the process and what is carrying it out is in the semantics of the noun phrase. (2/2)

Comment: According to this reasoning, the words 'sickening' and 'sickeningly' shouldn't exist, yet they're quite common and have the meaning of 'sickness inducing'. Can even be found with 'height': "THIS is the moment a schoolboy climbs out of a window and dangles from a sickening height - for Facebook likes." [The Sun](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/3652333/boy-hangs-off-ledge-for-facebook-likes/)

Comment: @DW256 The meaning of "sickening" in your example is different : [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sickening?q=sickening): "making you feel shocked or full of horror". It does not mean "making you sick".

Comment: @LPH Sure it does, like when you feel sick just thinking of it. The line of reasoning in your answer does not stand up to examination - any number of conditions designated using nouns or adjectives could induce sickness of either the physical, mental, or emotional varieties. Hence the widespread literal and figurative use of sickening(ly).

Comment: @DW256 The use of "sickening" has nothing to do in this question. What is relevant is that there are *sickness-inducing entities/agents*; I found an instance concerning motion:  [Biographical, physiological, and personality variables as predictors of performance under sickness-inducing motion](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/1981-24528-001).  Such occurrences of sickness induced by a situation are however comparatively rare; that is the point, they leave a trace mostly in very technical or scientific literature. You find "sickeningly" (off-topic,), but not "sickness-inducingly". (1/2)

Comment: @DW256 Don't you understand that when people say "I feel sick just thinking of it" they do not feel sick at all but instead they are trying to express their horror or disgust by telling you that their imagining the situation make them  see what it would do to them or to someone else? (2/2)

Comment: No, they feel sick. Their stomachs turn. They might throw up.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I truly believe that you do not speak your mind.